# I analyzed samples for arsenic with ICP-MS, my calibration standards are off. Any suggestions?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, mass-spectrometry

[image][image]I used a multi-element calibration standard (10 ppm, with As,Fe,Mg etc.) from a vendor. I then diluted this down to get calibration standards of 0, 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, and 100 ppb. I analyzed these standards along with my samples with ICP-MS.

My intensities for Fe, Ca, As, Mg aren't linear for my standards, and arsenic has the same intensities (0 or 7) for my standards. How is this possible? I attached a picture of my intensities. Also, I mostly care about arsenic.

If I made a mistake when preparing my standards would there not be at least an increase in As and Fe, Ca, and Mg, since the standard contains all elements.

Let me know if anyone has any suggestions.

Comment: Are your standards aqueous solutions ? How did you prepare your dilutions ? With pipettes ? Which volume did you mix with which volume water ? Were these dilutions made in glass bottles ? Which volume ?

Comment: Can you make a clean table so that it is readible? Also plot the calibration curve and show the concentration behavior, "not linear" does not tell the story.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Here is the table with the number of counts per second for the standards

Comment: @Maurice the standards are solutions and I used plastic tubes.